# Open Modal Pop Up in Page Load MVC2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I am new to MVC. The project that I am working on is on MVC2. The current requirement is to open a modal popup after login. Basically after successful login, the user will be redirected to a landing page, where i have to do some checks if i find the value more than zero, I have to open a modal pop up with a dropdown asking to make a selection, else show the default View.

Can anyone help me regarding the same.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you say,

> where i have to do some checks if i find the value more than zero

Do you already have this value? Or do you need to get one? If you need to get one:

A quick way of doing this would be to use `TempData`.

In the controller that contains the method for logging in, where the login is successful you can add:

```
TempData["login"] = 1;
```

Then in your view add:

```
@if (TempData["login"] != null)
{
    @*Display Modal*@
}
```

Do you need actually need help with the code of the modal?

You can see an example of a popup modal with a form here: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

Comment: Thanks Morgan. I would want to open a bootstrap modal